# Connect to a Fortinet VPN with Ubuntu

Tags: vpn, ipsec, fortinet

I don't know a lot about VPNs but I'd like to connect to a Fortinet VPN with Ubuntu.

I can connect on Windows using Forticlient just by entering the policy server (*vpn.theserver.com*) and then it asks for a user/password. I use IPSec.

Comment: I used strongSwan for connecting to FortiGate from Arch Linux. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/778487/connecting-to-a-fortigate-vpn-from-a-remote-linux-machine-via-openswan/897556#897556) for instructions.

Answer (score 32):

If you use SSL based VPN from Fortinet, you can use [openfortivpn](https://github.com/adrienverge/openfortivpn) software which is part of Ubuntu and Fedora.

```
$ sudo apt install -y openfortivpn || yum install -y openfortivpn
$ touch openfortivpn.conf
$ chmod go= openfortivpn.conf
```

Edit openfortivpn.conf:

```
host =
port =
username =
password =
# trusted-cert =
```

Connect the first time:

```
$ sudo openfortivpn -c openfortivpn.conf
ERROR:  Gateway certificate validation failed, and the certificate digest in not in the local whitelist. If you trust it, rerun with:
ERROR:      --trusted-cert  <some-random-string-to-add-to-trusted-cert>
```

Edit openfortivpn.conf file and update `trusted-cert` option with the string from the error. Make sure the option is not commented (remove the `#`).

Each time you need to connect, run:

```
sudo openfortivpn -c openfortivpn.conf
```

You could also do it straight through the command line and make an alias for it in your `.bashrc`. This is less secure as any user on the system will be able to see the password using `ps`.

```
sudo openfortivpn -u <USER> -p <PASSWORD> --trusted-cert <CERTIFICATE> <SERVER>:<PORT>
```

To disconnect press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: Worked fine in debian, after compiling operfortivpn from github

Comment: Worked for me like a charm on AWS Ec2 Ubuntu 18.04

Thank you so much

Comment: I always get a "Received bad header from gateway:" error after entering the 2factor authentication token. Guess it's time to secondboot windows sadly...

Comment: hey, if I want to add the pre-shared key into this config file, how I can do this?

Comment: Amazing job worked fine on Ubuntu 18.04 without any issue whatsoever

Answer (score 3):

Fortinet is just an IPSEC VPN server - you don't specifically need their client to connect to it.  The [IPSEC HOWTO](http://www.ipsec-howto.org/) details a list of various options you have for setting up a Linux VPN client.  There are also a few commercial linux IPSec clients such as [Shrewsoft.](http://www.shrew.net/software)

Comment: I found the Shrewsoft client on Linux to be almost as painful as using it on MSWindows - I switched to using vpnc - and never looked back.