# Fortinet SSL VPN Client Setup Without GUI on Linux (centos)

Tags: centos, vpn, terminal, fortinet

How can I install and setup a fortinet SSL VPN client on a VPS that's running on Centos?
I have problem to do it because all guide I have are all using GUI which is not installed on the VPS to save resource. (example: http://dbssolutions.freshdesk.com/solution/categories/1513/folders/3047/articles/1791-how-to-install-the-linux-fortinet-ssl-vpn-client)

I already have the linux version for the vpn client but not sure how to install and configure it only using the terminal.

Comment: @ben where did you get the cli client? i've download 2 different versions from fortinet support but none of them have cli support forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2010.tar.gz
forticlientsslvpn_linux_4.0.2012.tar.gz

Comment: just install xterm and requiered libraries on the vps and run the client with X over ssh (ssh -X user@host)

Comment: If there is a way to install .deb packages in CentOS, https://hadler.me/linux/forticlient-sslvpn-deb-packages/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to a Fortinet VPN with Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/152233/connect-to-a-fortinet-vpn-with-ubuntu)

Comment: @gfa  did you ever find the location of the CLI client?

Answer (score 12):

I spent a while trying to find documentation on this, and got this from a Fortinet Engineer.

1. Install  like any other  using tar.gz file Then run below command in
   linux CLI
2. Then run below command in linux CLI

`./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server 172.17.97.85:10443 --vpnuser forti`

Make sure the command run from the sslvpn directory.  Substitute the IP address with the one of your server .

Comment: Just as @ben-arent suggested you can use the cli client for linux. I found it here: http://supportwiki.thelinuxfix.com/wiki/index.php/Installing_the_Management_SSL-VPN_Client

Answer (score 7):

This is another short solution. Download & Install the client:

```
# wget -q http://kb.arubacloud.com/files/tar-gz/forticlientsslvpn_linux_4-0-2281-tar.aspx -O fortisslvpn.tgz && tar -xzf fortisslvpn.tgz
# cd forticlientsslvpn && ./helper/setup.linux.sh
```

Press Ctrl+C, Agree Their License (1st time only) & then connect to VPN by:

```
# yes | ./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server example_firewall_host:10443 --vpnuser example_user > /dev/null
```

Comment: Is the referenced package the official package or has it been modified?.

Answer (score 5):

You can try to configure your VPN without the Fortinet GUI. Here's a complete guide to IPSEC for linux http://www.ipsec-howto.org/ and you may want to try this:

The link is created by running pppd through a pseudo terminal that is created by pty-redir and connected to ssh. This is done with something similar to the following sequence of commands:

```
/usr/sbin/pty-redir /usr/bin/ssh -t -e none -o 'Batchmode yes' -c blowfish -i /root/.ssh/identity.vpn -l joe > /tmp/vpn-device
sleep 10

/usr/sbin/pppd `cat /tmp/vpn-device`
sleep 15

/sbin/route add -net 172.16.0.0 gw vpn-internal.mycompany.com netmask 255.240.0.0
/sbin/route add -net 192.168.0.0 gw vpn-internal.mycompany.com netmask 255.255.0.0
```

> What this does is run ssh, redirecting the input and output to pppd.
>   The options passed to ssh configure it to run without escape
>   characters (-e), using the blowfish crypto algorithm (-c), using the
>   identity file specified (-i), in terminal mode (-t), with the options
>   'Batchmode yes' (-o). The sleep commands are used to space out the
>   executions of the commands so that each can complete their startup
>   before the next is run.

From "[Bring up the link](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/VPN-HOWTO/x338.html)"

Next section, "[Scripting](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/VPN-HOWTO/x346.html)" may help you as well to configure and run your VPN client. There's additional information in the [ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient#Manually_configuring_your_connection).

Comment: Your answer is fine except OP was talking about SSL VPN (!IPSEC), have an upvote anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Coded some Expect script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn /opt/local/forticlientsslvpn/64bit/forticlientsslvpn_cli --server vpn_host:port --vpnuser user1
expect "Password for VPN:"
send "password\r"
#expect "*(Y/N)"
#send "Y\r"
interact
```

Answer (score 1):

On CentOS7, install `openfortivpn`.

`sudo yum install openfortivpn` and then try connect using

`sudo openfortivpn <ip-address>:<port> -u <user_name>` it gives the Gateway certification validation error.

`ERROR:  Gateway certificate validation failed, and the certificate digest is not in the local whitelist. If you trust it, ERROR:  --trusted-cert <alpha_numeric_cert>......`

Now re-run the above command by adding `--trusted-cert <alpha_numeric_cert>`.

`sudo openfortivpn <ip-address>:<port> -u <user_name> --trusted-cert <alpha_numeric_cert>`

Now it gives the vpn password prompt to connect. Check this [link](https://www.cs.unb.ca/help/vpn/centos.shtml) for reference.

P.S. Tried with [forticlientvpn](https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads/linux) but not succeeded in bringing X11 forwarding with `ssh -X user@ip-address' and ssh -Y user@ip-address` on my windows10 machine.
After SSH,`forticlient` command giving `connect 127.0.0.1 port 6000: Connection refused`

`(forticlient:24694): Gtk-WARNING **: 03:58:51.167: cannot open display: 10.0.2.165:11.0 error.`