# Fortinet SSL VPN Client Setup Without GUI on Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: ssl, vpn, fortinet

When I use

```
./forticlientsslvpn_cli --server 172.17.97.85:10443 --vpnuser forti
```

to connect to the vpn, (using Forticlient SSLVPN 4.4.2329-1 64bit & Forticlient SSLVPN 4.4.2327-2 64bit) it shows

```
STATUS::Connected
```

but I don't get an IP, so it did not really connect. Any ideas please?

Got info from [this ServerFault post](https://serverfault.com/questions/412220/fortinet-ssl-vpn-client-setup-without-gui-on-linux-centos/484988#484988?newreg=9f12134c83234e27bb2ec21784900b36).

Comment: Am I right in assuming this is on Ubunutu 16.04 LTS?

Answer (score 4):

I resolved the same issue in Ubuntu 16.04 by installing ppp

```
# apt-get install ppp
```

Comment: If you don't see the message `STATUS::Tunnel running` after `Press Ctrl-C to quit` you need ppp.

For CentOS/Redhat `yum install ppp` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Wait till you get message such as `STATUS::Tunnel running` , since tunneling takes time.  You can check if tunnel got created or not by using command

```
ifconfig ppp0
```

As I am able to connect to vpn using above CLI command from Ubuntu 16.04 , here is my console output:

```
STATUS::Login succeed
STATUS::Starting PPPd
STATUS::Initializing tunnel
STATUS::Connecting to server
STATUS::Connected
Press Ctrl-C to quit
STATUS::Tunnel running
```